# TypeError from type hint of multiple return

Tags: python, tuples, type-hinting

I have a definition

```
def test() -> tuple[int, int]:
    return 0,0
```

but the type hint yields an error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I give type hint on multiple return value???

Comment: You use syntax for Python 3.10 but are using an older version of Python.

Comment: Python 3.9 made `tuple` generic; prior to that you need to use `typing.Tuple` in its place.